# Language subdomains in Laravel with same document root

Tags: php, laravel

I am suppose to have three languages for my Laravel app:

domain.com (English)
de.domain.com (German)
fr.domain.com (French)

When creating the subdomains, I want to point them all to the same document root, where I have my application. I don't want to upload the same app to 3 directories.

Then the question is, how will the app know which language to use (i.e. which subdomain it's on).

My one idea is to manually parse the URL to get the subdomain, then select the language based on that. Is there is a better way to do this, based on Laravel docs or best practices?

Comment: Read this section in the documentation : https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization

Comment: That's how I would do it too. I would create a middleware that would define the locale based on the parsing.

Comment: you can also use environment variables, but that is set on the apache/php-fpm side. in php you would use either the $_ENV variable or getenv() to read it